# ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Timeout while fetching: RestTemplate

Tags: java, android, spring-3

I'm facing an issue with RestTemplate in Spring 3.0.
When I'm trying to request other app which is in Google App Engine application it is timeout for 5 secs.

My Client application and server application both are in Google App Engine,

Here is Client Code:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForObject( pUrl , paramObj , String.class )
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: 
   Timeout while fetching: http://naresh-app.appspot.com/HistoryAction/getHistory.json; 
nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
   Timeout while fetching: http://naresh-app.appspot.com/HistoryAction/getHistory.json
```

Comment: Did you set the socket timeout to something really low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is connection to internet is good? I think you can only handle exception and retro later.

Comment: It is fixed, it is an issue with Rest api, after updating it is working fine :)